# Different RedirectURL Google OAuth

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, google-oauth

Is it possible redirecting to other URL than request comes from?
I would like to redirect to localhost:4200.

(doing it to simplify dev)

[Google OAuth2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmKJD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You can change the path, but not the entire URI. In other words, the redirect has to be to the originating application. The reason is actually kind of obvious: there's cookies involved and those are domain-bound. Granted, those would be shared for your localhost sites, since ports don't matter, but in a real-world scenario, it wouldn't work. As a result, there's no functionality built-in to allow it.

Comment: What kind of workaround would u suggest? I do mean working on that data recieved from google on other port.

Comment: There's no workaround. You need the same site that initiates the OAuth request to handle the redirect. That's how this works. If you're somehow trying to share the auth, you should look into something like IdentityServer, which will give you a centralized auth provider. Each site redirects the user there to authenticate, where it handles the process end to end, and then provides the originating site with the user principal.

Comment: Thank u very much. I appreciate that :)